# Make a `ln -s` that checks for broken symbolic links

Tags: bash, symlink, ln

I am trying to write a function `ln()` (if it is not a good idea to call it `ln`, it may just be as well called `myln()` or whatever, but that is not important) in `bash`, such that,

- If the short option `-s` does not exist, it simply performs what `command ln` does
- If the short option `-s` does exist, it performs what `command ln` does unless the symbolic link(s) to be created contain broken ones. In that case, it prints a warning to stderr and does not create the link (or create it and remove it afterwards immediately)

Since the command `ln` takes its option in various forms that are extremely versatile, I am not sure how to write such a function to cover all the possibilities. I do know how to write it for simple usage like `ln -s [absolute path 1] [absolute path 2]`.

It is best if the function is able to cover the usages of `ln` in the newest version of `GNU` `coreutils` (at the time the question is asked the newest version is 8.31), but a function that just covers the usage in `POSIX` is fine too.

**Side note**: I have written a "failproof" `rm` in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/215226/155325, I want to do something similar to make a "failproof" `ln`. I am using it myself and I know the consequences. I am not distributing it to someone not familiar with Linux and say "Hey you should use this `rm` from now on and you can forget the caveats of `rm /*`"

Comment: See also the `-r`/`--relative` option of GNU `ln`

Comment: Actually I believe the most difficult part is reproducing the getopt(s) logic of `command ln`.

Comment: For that, you can use util-linux `getopt` or https://github.com/stephane-chazelas/misc-scripts/blob/master/getopts_long.sh.

Comment: See also GNU `realpath --relative-to`

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at your github repo.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're after but in your function you can use `namei` command to examine target file before creating a symbolic link.

```
$ touch file1
$ ln -s file1 file2
$ ln -s file2 file3
$ namei file3 
f: file3
 l file3 -> file2
   l file2 -> file1
     - file1
$ echo $?
0
$ rm file1 # break first symlink
$ ls -l
$ namei file3
f: file3
 l file3 -> file2
   l file2 -> file1
       file1 - No such file or directory
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess that is a starting point.